# Как реализовать получение результата Android In-app billing в fragment?

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchases

Не могу разобраться уже несколько дней. Как реализовать получение результата Android In-app billing в fragment? При совершении тестовой оплаты (после успешной оплаты покупки) ничего не происходит с первого раза, при клике второй раз (и последующие) на кнопку купить успешно выполняется действие из метода onProductPurchased. Почему действие после успешной покупки не выполняется с первого раза и как это решить? Все операции с биллингом происходят внутри фрагмента. Перечитал кучу информации в интернете и подобные вопросы, но не понял как решить эту проблему. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Мой код:

```
// Инициализация и кнопка в onCreateView
bp = new BillingProcessor(context, "Мой ключ", this);
bp.initialize();

// Клик по кнопке для оплаты
PayButt.setOnClickListener(
                                new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(View v) {

                                            // Выполняем оплату
                                            bp.purchase((Activity) context, ProductID);

                                    }
                                }
                        );
// Инициализация и кнопка в onCreateView

// Стандартные методы

// Оплата
@Override
public void onBillingInitialized() {
    /*
     * Вызывается, когда объект инициализирован и можно совершать покупки
     */
}

@Override
public void onProductPurchased(@NonNull String productId, TransactionDetails details) {

    /*
     * Вызывается когда покупка совершена
     */

    if (bp.isPurchased(productId)) {

       Toast toastTrue = Toast.makeText(context, "Оплата выполнена успешно!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toastTrue.show();

                    // Переходим на главную
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainController.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

    }

}

@Override
public void onBillingError(int errorCode, Throwable error) {
    /*
     * Вызывается при возникновении каких-либо ошибок при совершении покупки
     */
}

@Override
public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {
    /*
     * Вызывается один раз при первом запуске после установки или переустановки приложения.
     * Служит для получения приобретённых ранее покупок, например, на другом устройстве
     */
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (!bp.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможно onActivityResult вызывается в активити, не во фрагменте, оттого и проблемы. Посмотрите есть ли перегрузка метода `BillingProcessor#purchase()` принимающая фрагмент. Тогда будет вызван нужный метод и должно заработать. Иначе - придётся как-то прокидывать вызов из активити во фрагмент.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, где это можно посмотреть?) Спасибо

Comment: Ну.. Кто-то дебаггером пользуется, а можно просто в логи вывести что-то в нужных методах и посмотреть что и где выведется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Я уже пытался решить ее таким способом, но вставлял данный код не туда. Необходимо чтобы и в основном Activity был метод onActivityResult, который передавал данные в onActivityResult фрагмента. Код onActivityResult из основного Activity:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments())
    {
        if (fragment != null)
        {
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```